# Cryptocompare API

Tags: api

Anyone here using cryptocompare api? Where would be the best place to ask questions about it?

I am just starting with it and for example I have stumbled upon few issues. Like, coin tickers with an asterisk. As I receive them, some coins have symbol like "ABC*" and later when I try get its price information for both "ABC" and "ABC*" I get an error. On top of that, even few items with regular symbols constantly fail.

And there are other issues, like the meaning of the SortOrder key as I can not connect its value to the rank on the regular site, on cryptocompare front page..

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, the Cryptocompare API is kind of quirky and fickle.  That's part of the reason I use [Nomics' free API](https://p.nomics.com/cryptocurrency-bitcoin-api/).

Full disclosure: my team built the API to help us create Nomics.com, and then realized there was enough value there to make the API available to others. But Nomics.com 100% runs on the free version of our API (there are no hidden endpoints or backdoors), so anything you see us doing on the website is something you can do as well.

Comment: I down-voted your answer because it isn't answering the question (which could just be an oversight) but also because you seem to be advertising a competing API.  If you're not going to say anything about the CryptoCompare API, at least just use a comment instead of presenting your input as an answer.